# pandas convert text feature to numeric value

Tags: python, pandas

I can convert all text features in a pandas dataframe by casting to 'category' using the df.astype() method as below. However I find category hard to work with (eg for plotting data) and would prefer to create a new column of integers

```
#convert all objects to categories
object_types = dataset.select_dtypes(include=['O'])
for col in object_types:
    dataset['{0}_category'.format(col)] = dataset[col].astype('category')
```

I can convert the text to integers using this hack:

```
#convert all objects to int values
object_types = dataset.select_dtypes(include=['O'])

new_cols = {}
for col in object_types:
    data_set = set(dataset[col].tolist())
    data_indexed = {}
    for i, item in enumerate(data_set):
        data_indexed[item] = i
    new_list = []
    for item in dataset[col].tolist():
        new_list.append(data_indexed[item])
    new_cols[col]=new_list

for key, val in new_cols.items():
    dataset['{0}_int_value'.format(key)] = val
```

But is there a better (or existing) way to do the same?

Comment: I'd switch your answer to MaxU's answer. It's more appropriate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use [factorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) method, which is designed for this particular task:

```
In [90]: x
Out[90]:
    A  B
9   c  z
10  c  z
4   b  x
5   b  y
1   a  w
7   b  z

In [91]: x.apply(lambda col: pd.factorize(col, sort=True)[0])
Out[91]:
    A  B
9   2  3
10  2  3
4   1  1
5   1  2
1   0  0
7   1  3
```

or:

```
In [92]: x.apply(lambda col: pd.factorize(col)[0])
Out[92]:
    A  B
9   0  0
10  0  0
4   1  1
5   1  2
1   2  3
7   1  0
```

Comment: What if i want to apply this to specific columns ?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu, just apply it to specific columns ;)

Comment: An example for the same?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu, i'd encourage you to ask a new question, specify there a small input sample dataset and your desired dataset

Answer (score 4):

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('aaaabbbbcccc'),
                       B=list('wwxxxyyzzzzz')))

df
```

[image]

you can convert to integers like this

```
def intify(s):
    u = np.unique(s)
    i = np.arange(len(u))
    return s.map(dict(zip(u, i)))
```

or shorter version

```
def intify(s):
    u = np.unique(s)
    return s.map({k: i for i, k in enumerate(u)})

df.apply(intify)
```

Or in a single line

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.map({k:i for i,k in enumerate(s.unique())}))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried applying both the intify method and lambda function to the dataframe and after printing .head for the dataframe before and after application, the dataframe is unchanged (still strings not ints)

Comment: @DonSmythe you have to assign the results back to the dataframe.  In my case, `df = df.apply(intify)`